# Are neural networks inherently imperfect because they mimic an imperfect machine (human)?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

Neural networks are the base for all(most?) of the machine learning / deep learning algorithms/programs.

Humans don't have fixed algorithms to decide or do something. Initially, we don't know how a snake is supposed to look. **We learn** that **from experience**. But our learning is never perfect. Once in a while, we mistake a black wire lying on the floor for a snake. Or **we mistake the snake for a wire**.

Given that **neural networks are using the same technique as humans, are they inherently imperfect?** Surely, we can make the self-driving network much better than best human, but that is because it got much more experience(24x7) than the human. **But can we guarantee it's perfectness?**(**mathematically, or at least by testing**, enough to make people trust in the programs)

---

I have this question because of the moral implications ML programs bring. I guess this will cause a lot of problem in adopting these technologies, especially when human life is at stake(eg. surgeon, self-driving cars, self-flying jets) as humans would rather rely on an imperfect human than a lesser imperfect AI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to think of neural networks as inspired by human biology, not that they're using exactly the same mechanism.

The notion of "inherently imperfect" isn't well-defined, so the question isn't meaningful.  And, no, neural networks aren't always imperfect.  For instance, suppose the learning task was "label everything 0".  If you give a neural network a training set with one million examples, all of which have the label 0, then the neural network might well learn to output label 0 on all possible inputs.

As far as moral implications, it's not clear that it matters much *why* neural networks are imperfect; what's important is that they are often imperfect.  But moral implications are probably more a matter of the study of ethics and philosophy than the science of computing, so I'll leave that there.

Finally, I encourage you to avoid binary thinking.  Don't divide the world into "perfect" vs "imperfect".  An engineer would say that in practice nothing is perfect; it's all about degrees of imperfection.  One system might be good enough, or better than the reasonably available alternatives, even if it's not 100% perfect.